# encoding a unicode string for lzma compression

Tags: python-2.7, compression, python-unicode

I have a Unicode string - under Python 2.7.

I also have a headache today – a real one that was not caused by Unicode – and can't maintain focus on the problem as much as I need to.  I'm more mindless-drone than thinker until the pollen count drops.

I need to compress my 'string' using `backports.lzma`.  Occasionally I get an error, because the 'string' is not an ASCII compatible `String` but a `Unicode` object that uses some currently unknown character set (probably UTF-8 but no guarantee).  `lzma.compress` wants a `String` or `bytes()` compatible object.

I don't necessarily have the character encoding of the unicode at this point in my code.  I just know that it's a unicode object.  Usually in a similar situation I know the encoding and can act appropriately.  I also usually don't care about losing a character or two in transcoding.  This time I care.

This leads me to a few questions:

• Is there a safe encoding to choose that will also be somewhat minimal in size (for a majority of utf-8 docs)?

• Do I need to worry about backwards compatibility on decoding vs the earlier documents I've compressed?  I did not fully read the `lzma` docs (my bad) and didn't realize it needed a `String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compression operates on bytes, not text, so naturally it takes a `str` (2.x) or `bytes` (3.x) object. You don't need to care what the internal text representation is since you will encode/decode the text yourself.

> - Is there a safe encoding to choose that will also be somewhat minimal in size (for a majority of utf-8 docs)?

Nope. Just encode as UTF-8 and be done with it.

> - Do I need to worry about backwards compatibility on decoding vs the earlier documents I've compressed? I did not fully read the lzma docs (my bad) and didn't realize it needed a String.

If you've only compressed ASCII text then you can decode as UTF-8 without issue, since UTF-8 and ASCII encode ASCII text exactly the same way.

Comment: Thanks. I knew that UTF8 supersets ASCII, but was worried if I needed to choose some other encoding to ensure everything gets through.  BTW, the brevity of your answers is incredibly perfect.

Comment: All UTF encodings can encode all Unicode characters, by definition. UTF-8 is the least wasteful when it comes to encoding ASCII text.